# what does getcmd do in Joomla

Tags: joomla

Hi all I am new to programming in Joomla.  I am going through the Joomla Programming book by Mark Dexter and Louis Landry.  Which for the most part is a good book.

My question is what does  $view = JRequest::getCmd('view', 'submanager');  do?

I know it is returning something to the $view variable, but not sure what.  Is it looking for the word view as a request URL param?  What is submanager?

Any clarity in this matter would be great.

Thanks in advance
Dean-O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCmd` is a proxy function for `getVar` The difference being is that `getCmd` only allows words and integers based on `[A-Za-z0-9.-_]`.

`getVar` simply fetches a variable that you ask it to, depending on the request method, such as a POST or GET request.

Do bare in mind that `JRequest` is deprecated, therefore should you need to fetch a variable, then use the following:

```
$jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$variable = $jinput->get('view', 'submanager');
```

### Example:

Lets say you have a small contact form and within that form is an input field which has `name="email"`.

Once that form is submitted, you can then access this using:

```
$jinput   = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$variable = $jinput->get('email');
```

---

So in your case, the code you provided is getting the variable `view`, ensuring it is a word or number and `submanager` is the default value for this variable.

Comment: Great answer @Lodder, couldn't explain better myself.

Comment: My question is what does this do.  Is it looking for the word view as a request URL param?   if so, then What is submanager for or do?

Comment: @Dean-O - I have updated my answer with an example. I hope this explains things for a you a little bit more

Comment: Bingo that did it.  The submanager is the value assigned if no view is found in the URL  (JRequest) is basically the URL being passed, right?